# WooCommerce - Redirect Logged In Users Based on their Role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

This is a query based around WooCommerce Membership and Subscriptions.

I must add that I'm also trying to decide if it's good UX to do what I'm doing.

There are many solutions to redirecting users after they log in but I have a situation where I want to redirect a user with the role of 'subscriber' when they click on specific links to pages that describe and allow you to become a member. So although I don't want to hide 'join now' etc I just want those to redirect to the my-account page.

Again there are various roles and redirect plugins but none seem to help in this specific scenario. So the source of the code I've used is here: [SOURCE](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/redirect-users-to-custom-pages-by-role--wp-33505) and I'm looking to do something like this:

```
function eks_redirect_users_by_role() {

    global $post;
    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];


    if ( 'subscriber' === $role_name && $post->ID == 47145)  {
        wp_redirect( '/my-account' );
    } 

} 

add_action( 'admin_init', 'eks_redirect_users_by_role' );
```

So if the user role is a subscriber and they try and visit the page idea it's redirected.

At the current time, it does fall back to a product page which says 'you already have a membership' but it's multiple steps to arrive.

Comment: Do your code redirect to my account page or not? Please explain exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: Let's say you are a member of a site already. Obviously in that site you could still click on links that redirect you to places on the site where you can buy a membership. I want anyone who already has a membership subscription to be redirected to their account page. The only way I could think of doing this would be to actually redirect the page when someone who has the role of subscriber. So I'd need something that takes the page ID and the user role into account. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You are preventing subscriber user to not open a page with an certain ID. Has that been worked for you? and what issue are you facing?

Comment: Please refer to my original post and previous answer to your query.

Comment: I couldn't get it after reading both so i am trying to know from you in comment.

Comment: Just to update. if you visit a site with a page with information of how to become a member with a button to subscribe to a membership that's fine, but if you are already a member I simply wanted to redirect the user to their account page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve want I wanted to the following way:

```
function eks_redirect_user() {

    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];
    $postid = get_the_ID();

    if ( 'subscriber' === $role_name && $postid == 47145  ) { ?>
        <script>
function redirectPage() {

    window.location = "/my-account/";
}

redirectPage();
</script>

<?php
        exit;
    }

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'eks_redirect_user' );
```

The issue is it's a fairly untidy solution as the redirect feels odd. I'm not sure if using wp_redirect would work better. I decided to do was just disable the button on the page with the main membership information rather than redirecting every call to action to the account page which seems like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more useful and proper way to achieve your request.

```
function redirection_based_user_role(){

    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];
    $postid         = get_the_ID();

    if ( 'subscriber' === $role_name && $postid == 47145  ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/my-account' ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirection_based_user_role' );
```

Hope this works.